# Video camera that outputs in HDMI in real time, 60 FPS, at least 720p, with zoom functionality

Tags: displays, projector

Is there a video camera that can output in HDMI real time 60 FPS, with a least a 720p resolution and with zoom functionality?

I'd like to be able to easily display things on a larger HDMI screen with low latency. (tablet, phone, papers, objects, etc.)

Comment: Any modern DSLR or mirrorless ought to be able to do that. Probably the same for any kind of 'handycam' if they're still being made in this age of smartphones. What research have you done so far?

Comment: Given I don't know what to look for, this is my research. Thanks for pointing in a direction. Is there a certain spec to look for so I can use it to compare options? Primarily I'd like to minimize the delay response between the image capture on the device and the projection on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given I don't know what to look for, this is my research.

your specs of **HDMI** and **60 fps** and **at least 720p** are pretty low... such that a 10 year old might laugh and say my phone does better...

what used to be 30fps and 720p, the norm now is 60 fps and 1080p.

my motorola phone for example:
https://www.verizon.com/smartphones/motorola-edge-5g-uw/
video : 4K UHD (30fps), FHD (60/30fps)

FHD = full high definition @ 1920 x 1080p, which is now becoming the old standard.
UHD = ultra high definition which is the now common 4k resolution at 3840 x 2160p.

Both are 16:9

off the shelf go-pro's and knockoffs are all 4k these days, typically at 30fps.

but just google `4k 60fps camera or camcorder` for starters

if you buy a high end video camera you can almost always dial its settings down from 4k to 1920x1080 and 30fps.

most everything is going to show up as *still* camera, but they all have video recording capability so look at the video recording specs.  Find the one supporting the largest SDHC card you're willing to buy, 4k @ 60fps will eat up storage quick.

https://camerajabber.com/which-cameras-shoot-4k-video-at-60fps/

*Which cameras can output 4k60 via HDMI*
https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4475627

spoiler: Fujifilm X-T3 about $1000 and Panasonic camcorder WXF995 about $800

Comment: https://camerajabber.com/buyersguides/which-cameras-shoot-4k-at-120fps/

Comment: you need this: $30k 8k @ 120fps: https://www.techtimes.com/articles/264887/20210901/red-8k-pro-camera-adds-new-sensor-allowing-120-fps-raw-video-worth-29-580.htm

Comment: https://filmora.wondershare.com/8k/best-8k-cameras.html

Comment: and don't discount using wifi or bluetooth instead of a hardline hdmi connection, especially with all the new tv and tablet displays supprting 802.11 ac and ax (wifi6/6e) these days.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into it and see what works. Keep in mind I'm most interested in low-latency real-time display, not recording. Low specs are deliberate; I'm hoping to find something that's as cheap as possible.

Comment: Then I would scour ebay for old camcorders